# How to do in C language inline Assembly language forloop?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, inline-assembly

How can i do inline C pure Assembly language? I wanted to do for loop but does not works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  asm 
  {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    { 
         // is this how i will do the assembly language as inline C?
         // is this how the for loop looks as inline c?
    } 
  } // ?
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `asm { }` block? I'm not sure what you're expecting, but it certainly isn't what it actually does.

Comment: your question is not very clear. `for` loops are a `C` construct (present in a lot of other languages too), but do not exist in "pure assembly". Are you after the syntax for inline assembly in `C`? If that is the case, you'll need to tell us what compiler you use and what specifically you don't understand in its documentation. If you're wondering how to implement for loops in assembly, you'll need to tell what target architecture you're after, and show what you have tried/researched so far.

Comment: Yes, what CPU is it?  I am guessing x86 of course.

Comment: SPARC, I686, I386 3 CPU i want to test.

Comment: Why do you want to do that??? An optimizing compiler will most probably generate an almost perfectly optimized loop from your C source.

Comment: I want to make libraries in C for interface. Which does direct bridge of Assembly to another interface. C is just a wrapper for other languages. Example: Javascript -> C -> Assembly communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to,

```
__asm{
        xor esi,esi
go:
        inc esi
        cmp esi,10
        jnz go

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it would have been more pedagogical to initialize esi with a move instead.

Comment: @Amigable Yeah, except nobody does that so you might as well introduce it here :-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because that isn't assembly. IIRC, the simplest `for`-like loop in assembly is something like

```
.L3:
    addl    $1, -4(%ebp)
    cmpl    $9, -4(%ebp)
    jle     .L3
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use asm keyword you aren't allow to write any C code. You can only use assembly language keywords and the way of writing assembly code in C depends on complier. Every compiler allow you in different way. For Example Turbo uses this syntax

```
void main()
{
   asm
   {
      mov ax,4C00h
      int 21h
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what he's asking is if it's possible to write "inline C" in an assembly language program.  The answer would be no, you'll have to compile your C program in to a library and call it from your assembly language program.  I suppose you could also write a macro to make implementing the for loop more convienient in assembly, but that would be highly assembler dependant and you would have to let us know which you are using.  I apoligize if I'm wrong, I'm just taking a shot in the dark here, your question wasn't quite clear.

Comment: I would like to have main.c file which is C. And inside that file i would like to have my Assembly code also. When i will compile and run main.c file it will run actually C and Assembly mixer. Without using external as.

Comment: @89899.3K - You can have both in the same source file, but not mixed. Inside the `asm{ }` you can only have assembler code. That's what the `asm` means!

Answer (score 0):

Check the flow control instructions to know how to implement loops with assembly language. Check out the x86 conditional jump instructions, and the `LOOPX` instructions. Have a look http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow  . For better and in-detail description check intel's manual.